# Clarification regarding NULL pointers in context of Binary Tree

Tags: c++, pointers, null, binary-tree, nodes

I have a data structure like:

```
struct node
{
   int count;
   node *left,*right;
   node(int count,node* l,node*r)
   {
      this->count=count;
      this->left=l;
      this->right=r;
   }
   node* update(int l,int r,int v);
};
```

Now I declare a global variable:

`node* p=new node(0,NULL,NULL);`

So this statement will cause `p` to have :

```
p->count=0;  
p->left=NULL;
p->right=NULL;
```

My question is what happens if I write `p->left=p->right=p;`. As far as I understand, it will give memory to `p->left` and `p->right` which were NULL initially.
So, it would be:

```
p->left->count=0, p->left->left=NULL,p->left->right=NULL;
p->right->count=0, p->right->left=NULL,p->right->right=NULL;
```

But I do not think that's what happening because when I am calling
`update(0,9,0)` where l=0, r=9 and v=0, it is working fine if i have
written the statement `p->left=p->right=p` before calling this
function.
But it fails to run if I comment this statement (i.e. it tries to access
NULL pointer values I guess).
Please clarify this doubt.

Comment: node* node::update(int l,int r,int v) {
    if(l<=v && v<=r)
    {
        if(l==r)
        {
            return new node(this->count+1,p,p);
        }
        int m=(l+r)>>1;
        return new node(this->count+1,this->left->update(l,m,v),this->right->update(m+1,r,v));
    }
    return this;}

Comment: Please put all relevant information into your question. Including e.g. the implementation of update. As it is here, one can only guess what you did, what you are trying to do and what your error is - and guessing won't help you with your question. (It might also help to only format Code as Code and not everything)

Comment: `p->left=p->right=p` create loops in your graph...

Comment: @Anedar, I tried to add the definition of update(), but when i did, I was not able to submit the question as it says "too much code". As far as formatting everything is concerned, thanks for the feedback. Will keep in mind the next time.

Answer (score 0):

> But i do not think that's what happening because when  i am calling

You're right. Actually, `p->left->left` is *not* `NULL`. It is `p`. Same goes for `right`.
That's because you are assigning them to `p`:

```
p->left = p->right = p;
```

So, when you do `p->left->left` you are doing `p->left` and thus `p`. There's a circular pointer here. `p` points to its own instance.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `p->left = p->right = p` will assign both `p->left` and `p->right` to have the value `p`.

There is no "giving memory" involved.

`p->left` and `p->right` will both contain the same address as `p`.   So `p->left`, `p->right`, and `p` all point to the same object.